# Rigging a Bone to a Mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

When I try to Rig an armature with automatic weights nothing is happening.
 And yes I am clicking the mesh then clicking the armature.
[image]

Is`nt the armature supposed to follow the mesh.

Comment: You have to parent the mesh to the armature. And select pose mode. The mesh follows the armature.

Comment: Look at the picture. the object is parented. But not aligned like I said.

Comment: I am on mobile, if he has put the automatic weights when aligned, and then moved the mesh it doesn't matter

Answer (score -1):

Both must be aligned.

The **automatic weight** will find the **closest mesh** to deform.

See the test below.

The first test: I aligned the first and make parenting with authomatic weights. It deforms perfectly.

The second test: I just apllied the same parenting but with armature and object not aligned. It will deform just the mesh closed to the bones.

[image]